# JQuery Post within IFrame not working

Tags: jquery, iframe

I'm trying to display a message based on the result of an $.post request sent from an IFrame to another processor file.

```
//begin script
function sendForm() {
$.post("http://www.website.com/main/post.php",$("#testForm").serialize(),function(data,status){
$("#result").html(data)
});
return false
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#testForm").submit(sendForm);
});

//end script

//form in an IFrame
//the IFrame is in a url like http://website.com/main/module/footer.php
<form id="testForm" method="post">
<label for="email">Enter your email</label>
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" required="yes" validate="email" message="Please enter a valid email address" class="replaceText" value="Enter your email"/>
<input id="subscribe" type="image" src="signup.png"/>
</form>

//this is where output from $.post request should be displayed
<div id="result"></div>
//end
```

I have tried doing the following and it works fine, the message from the $.post is displayed,

```
//scripts were disabled/commented out
//form in an IFrame
<form id="testForm" action="http://www.website.com/main/post.php" method="post">
<label for="email">Enter your email</label>
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" required="yes" validate="email" message="Please enter a valid email address" class="replaceText" value="Enter your email"/>
<input id="subscribe" type="image" src="signup.png"/>
</form>

<h5><div id="result"></div></h5>
```

however, because the form is within an IFrame it loads the whole IFrame displaying the message from the script. I need only for the  to show the message without ruining the whole IFrame.

Note: I need to keep the IFrame and cannot change the file post.php.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to give your iframe a `name` on the main page, and instead of

```
$("#result").html(data)
```

say

```
$('#result', frames['myFrameName'].document).html(data)
```

Comment: Still not working. Thank you though.

Additional info. When I change the request page to a file within the directory like "post2.php", the request is successful displaying the message to <div id="result"><div>..

But I need to access the built page at e.g. "http://www.website.com/main/post.php"

Comment: What I'm wondering is why I can't retrieve the results from http://www.website.com/main/post.php through $.post. But if the url is pointing to a file within the same directory, it can retrieve the results.

Comment: They're two different websites? That wasn't clear from your question. In that case, you can't use `$.post` due to cross-site scripting protections.